Flutter CupertinoContextMenu with subtree GestureDetector onTap - if push a route causes widget stuck on screen
I have a problem with CupertinoContextMenu and GestureDetector onTap callback in subtree.
If onTap is used to go to another route and the animation of CupertinoContextMenu is ongoing before value reach CupertinoContextMenu.animationOpensAt this causes a stuck of that widget on screen.

this is the code:
      CupertinoContextMenu.builder(
        enableHapticFeedback: true,
        actions: [
          // all actions of pop up menu
        ],
        builder: (context, animation) {
          return Material(
            elevation: 0,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: CardCustom(
              onTap: () {
                // function to push route
              },


I try to check animation value with:

            if (animation.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
              callback = onTap;
            }

or others similar code.
I tried to use this solution with timer:
      GestureDetector(
        onPanDown: (_) {
          stopwatch.start();
        },
        onPanCancel: () {
          pressTime = stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds;
          if (pressTime < 300) {
            // function to push route
          }
          stopwatch.reset();
          stopwatch.stop();
        },
        child: CupertinoContextMenu.builder(
           // code here


but the onTap function time frame is too short to work correctly
